# CSS transform + Icomoon

Tags: html, css, icons, css-transforms, icomoon

I have the following button

```
<a href="<?php echo get_permalink(18); ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-primary btn-back">
    <span class="icon">
        <span class="icomoon icon-arrow-01"></span>
    </span>
    News / Tips
</a>
```

...and I'm trying to flip the icon horizontally like so:

```
.btn-back .icomoon::before {
    -moz-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -o-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    -webkit-transform: scale(-1, -1);
    transform: scale(-1, -1);
}
```

I've also added `display: inline-block;` to the `[class^="icon-"], [class*=" icon-"]` as per what I read on a different post on here.

But when I view in my browser, the icon isn't flipped. I've also tried transforming the parent `.icon` container instead, but with no luck

Comment: inline-block should be applied to the transformed element which is `::before` here not its parent

Comment: @TemaniAfif thanks that works!